# How to take part without knowing the id, class - selenium firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

Can someone tell me how I can get element from page (Screen, button "Zaloguj") when I haven't name and id this element. When I try use something like this:

`FindElement(By....)` then here I have nothing what I can use or I don't know. I'm trying use class name like **btn btn-70** but then I take error .. then later try "**btn-btn-70**" or "**btn_btn-70**" and still have error.

I want make autogo to some page, sendKeys to login, password and then I want press button "Zaloguj" and later I will press some object on page etc.

Now I use **(selenium firefox)** code like this:

```
RemoteWebDriver d = Driver;

d.Navigate().GoToUrl(strona_www_tb.Text);
d.FindElementByName("user_mail").SendKeys("email@wp.pl");
d.FindElementByName("user_pass").SendKeys("haslo");
```

All is in windowsForm c#

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt5LN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying submit the form.
You can try using [submit](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit()) method

```
driver.findElement(By.name("user_pass")).submit();
```

Comment: Fantastic is works :D, very thanks :). I have one more question, maybe you can tell me. I have few messages under my mbox and I want get all without write under code id this message ex. I have message "mbox_5387989" next "mbox_5472074" etc. and I want take all message from mbox. Is possible get all object from here which start "mbox_" ?? and put this all under some List?


[Screen](http://www.fotosik.pl/zdjecie/71c70bee78eec458)

Comment: I think i understand your question, Yes you can use xpath in this way .//*[contains(@attribude,'mbox')] and use findElements to read everything into a list and then uou can iterate through it.

Comment: Excellently! : D I know how to click on these buttons, download items knowing part of the id and so on. :) Now I have to drawn about the general outline of the application and start to encode :) thanks :)